# What does this line mean?

Tags: meaning, words

So this line is from a song. Its

> とうとう　たらりたらりら
>
> たらりあがりいららりどう
>
> ちりやたらりたらりら
>
> たらりあがりららりどう

Okay so this line is written in the booklet itself, because of that this line is part of the lyrics and I assume has a meaning. But I don't know what this line/words mean or what it refers to. And there is this too

> たらりりら
>
> たららりら
>
> らりどう
>
> 永く絶えずおはしませよ

What I have in mind is this is onomatopoeia for something or  a line that refer to something or a word that I don't know.

P.S. since I don't think I can post the full lyrics of the song, the language used in the song is more traditional and the song itself is like a wishes(long life and good health) to everyone rather than nowadays song/pop songs(hope that helps a little)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your quote seems to be a part of lyrics of [幻想萬歳楽](https://www31.atwiki.jp/touhoukashi/pages/1915.html), a Touhou fansong. But it is apparently an homage to an old [Noh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noh) play usually known as [翁（おきな）](http://www.the-noh.com/jp/plays/data/program_067.html):

> シテ　上「**とうどうたらりたらりら。たらりあがりららりどう**
>   地　　上「**ちりやたらりたらりら。たらりあがりらららりどう**
>   シテ　上「所千代までおはしませ
>   地　　上「我等も千秋さむらはふ
>   シテ　上「鶴と亀との齢にて
>   地　　上「幸心に任せたり
>   シテ　上「**とうどうたらりたらりらたらりら**
>   地　　上「**ちりやたらりたらりら。たらりあがりららりどう**
>   千歳　下「鳴るは滝の水。鳴るは滝の水日は照る
>   地　　上「絶えず**とうたり　ありうどうどうどう**
>   千歳　下「絶えず**とうたり**。常に**たうたり**

(an example of script from [here](http://www5.plala.or.jp/obara123/u0171okina.htm))

This play is traditionally performed as a ritual that commemorates "the origin of Noh" rather than an ordinary play. Due to its ancient and obscure background, the bolded part of script has been known to scholars as incomprehensible, mysterious phrases.

There are theories claim that it could be "shouted out melody", "onomatopoeia", "Buddist incantation", "Korean phrase", or even "Tibetan phrase", but generally considered too corrupted to reasonably reconstruct. So in today's perspective, it is nothing more than meaningless chant or spell.

See also: [「とうとうたらりたらりら」は陀羅尼歌か : 〈翁〉冒頭句の起原をめぐって](https://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/120005426503)